# Java - If I change an item in a list, will the Object in the list be changed too?

Tags: java, arraylist

I know this has probably been asked before but I can't find a specific answer to my specific question. I have already tried to grasp Java's handling of references but this still puzzles me. Consider the following:

```
public class Question
{
    private boolean isCorrect;

    public void setCorrect (boolean _isCorrect) {
        isCorrect = _isCorrect;
    }
}
```

Now, in another file, somewhere in the code:

```
/**
* questionList is List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
* With various Question's added already with various isCorrect values.
*/
for (int i = 0; i < questionList.size(); i++) {
    Question q = (Question) questionList.get(i);
    q.setCorrect(true);
}
```

Will this set each Question's `isCorrect` in the `questionList` to **true**? As I understand Java (and I don't think I do) it should. But does it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will. It's the same object referenced in two places.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should learn about pointers and references from the Java Tutorial. The List contains pointers to the slots in memory where the Question is stored. So take actions on the pointer, you are taking actions on the sot in memory itself

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. Understand this

```
Question q = (Question) questionList.get(i);
```

`q` is simply a reference of type `Question` that refers to the underlying object returned by `get`. No copy of the object is implicitly created.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the variable `q` is pointing to the object in the list in memory. Therefore, any methods you call on `q` are getting called on the object in memory.

Answer (score -1):

It should be changed to true, but for speed's sake, why not:

```
   for(int loop = 0; i < questionList.size(); loop++){
       questionList.get(loop).setCorrect(true);
   }
```